QGIS -> Model designer -> using Shortest Path (Run in Batch Process)
I'm using QGIS 3.34.0, and making a litle model using Model Designer. I have lots of tractor roads and I need to calculate distances from each crossing of two roads to the highway road. I make points on those crossing points, and make a point on the crossing tractor road with the highway road.
I'm using (outside a Model Designer) Shortest Path (Point to layer) but Run as Batch Process and it gives me results.
Is there any way to use it in Model Designer?
I need a distace from each red point to the purple point on the road folowing blue line...

And I am using Shortest path in Batch procesing - and I am trying to put this process in my model.


Instead of batch you can iterate over each start point using a Vector Features input.
Create a model with three input parameters:

Vector Features: Start points
Vector Layer: End points
Vector Layer: The line network


Set the start point  in Shortest path (point to layer) to "Pre-calculated Value" with the expression:
concat(  @vector_features_minx , ',',  @vector_features_miny , '[EPSG:3006]')
Replace EPSG:3006 with the coordinate system of the input points.
The expression will create a string in the format: X start coordinate , Y start coordinate [EPSG:3006] for each input start point feature.
When you execute the model, press "Iterate over this layer ... ":

One shortest path layer is created for each input point, which you can merge into one layer if you want to:


This helped a lot and gives the result I wanted.
And now, can I have one more little help: Using your instructions and tips, I assembled the model and the result of the model is from several to several dozen temporary files -> how, i.e. with which command, to merge them all into one. I tried with Merge vector layers, but I didn't get the desired result, which is 1 file with all merged data.
Thank you.

You have to merge them manually outside/after the model

You can use pyqgis for this. processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':[x for x in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values() if x.name()=="path"],'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}) will merge all layers named path that are added to the map.

Thanks a lot for all your help!
